# US NRI investing in India

Tags: stocks, india, broker, fbar, nse-india

I am planning to invest in India. It does not matter whether brokerages offer online or offline options, I am fine with both. I am not looking to invest in India-ETF's or India-funds like MINDX.

My question is which specifically which brokerages in India accept US NRI's ?

Comment: Product/service recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Most if not all brokers [Including those from large Govt or Private Banks] accept NRI trading. You would need to have an NRI bank account. An PINS-Demat Account and an NRI Brokerage account. Almost all brokers offer online platform and this would be more preferred rather than offline.

It would be easier if you have all the three accounts from same financial institution.