# How to invest in Index Funds in India?

Tags: india, non-resident, index-fund

Being a Non-residential Indian (NRI), and being a complete "Newbee" in investment, I wish to know, how to invest in Index Fund in India? What steps are needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [US NRI investing in India](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/59345/us-nri-investing-in-india)

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon and that was closed as off-topic.

Comment: @RonJohn Feel free to close this as off-topic if you feel like it; I'm just not making a value judgment in that regard. What is more clear-cut, to me, is that an appropriate answer to the question has already been posted to that question. 5 votes to close will close a question, even if they use different reasoning (but, the majority choosing a particular reason will determine the text used. So, if 3 people say 'vote to close because off-topic', that is what will appear after this is closed.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I think this is a completely **on**-topic question, since it's not asking for any specific bank or fund information (and so refused to vote for closure).

Answer (score 2):

Most Indian bank allow you to invest in index funds from netbanking login.

Get in touch with your Indian bank where you have NRE account.

Note if you invest via NRE account there is no tax implications in India. There may be tax implications in your country of residence.

Answer (score 0):

If you are NRI & particularly from US/Canada, There would be very few fund houses which would allow you to invest in their schemes.(active as well as passive). Keep this in mind. 
Also, your bank account needs to be NRE to invest.